# REST APIs over https

Tags: java, spring, rest, https

I want to host REST APIs over https. REST web services will be written in java probably using spring framework.

These web services will be accessed by java clients (not web browsers), probably using `org.apache.http` lib.

I am not getting clear picture of working with SSL certificates. 
My questions are -

1. What configurations will be required to host REST web services over "https"?
2. What configurations will be required at client side for accessing these "https" URIs?
3. Do I need to buy trusted SSL certificate for REST server or open java keygen will do?
4. Do I need the same/different certificate copy on REST client too?

Comment: See this topic http://www.maximporges.com/2009/11/18/configuring-tomcat-ssl-clientserver-authentication/ . It very practical, but it shows how to generate client and server certificates and configure tomcat.

Comment: @Evgeni Given link was very helpful.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. No particular configuration, you just need https activated.
2. No particular configuration, you just need to take care to use libs that check the certificate.
3. If you write the client, you can use a self signed one, and customize the client to check if it's your certificate. If anybody can write a client, it's better to have a publicly trusted certificate. WARNING : the free let's encrypt certificate are NOT trusted by java !
4. Why do you want a certificate on your client ?

Side note: if your API is publicly accessible, I strongly advise you do NOT redirect http to HTTPS but instead makes HTTP systematically answer an error. If you don't do so, a developer that use by mistake the http will NOT see the error and that will create security risks.

Comment: Sorry but still not clear with the 4th point... I am going to write REST server as well as REST client myself. My basic idea for using https instead of http is to send and receive encrypted data for security purpose.

Comment: @Mishty The server use a certificate to authenticate himself, the client verify that certificate. (It exists a mode where the client can authenticate himself too with another certificate,  but I think it's not what you are looking for)

Comment: @Tom so just activate the SSL on the domain will do? Rather than configuring it from let's say the spring security within the coding?